# Display button based on database role

Tags: php, mysql, database, roles

I have a MySQL database with a PHP frontend. Is possible in PHP to create something like *admin permission* on `button`? Can i put on my "download" `button` permission to only *admin* can access it? (only admin can download `excel` table with some information)

Sorry for my bad English.

[image]

Comment: Yes. You can. But you're not going to find "add permission button to php", just like you won't find a tool named  "build a house" at the hardware store.

Comment: What you have to distinguish superadmin and user?

Comment: what you might search on is "PHP How to create Admin Page" or the like. Or an Admin section of the page for conditional button creation

Comment: @Marc B i know it is not that easy... i just need help how to find something like that

Comment: @SHAZ i make two tables in mysql for admin and some users and stucked there :D

Comment: @Drew is better just to create an admin page? it is great idea

Comment: I am a big fan for spending a nickel, like [this](https://codecanyon.net/item/sharelock-standalone-version-with-admin-panel/7133065?s_rank=18) concept. I can't vouch for it. I know in the past that 10 to 15 bucks on codecanyon saved me a week. Let some other sucker slave on it. Rip out just the part you want. Just go search that site for "Admin"

Comment: Also see [How to set up user roles and permissions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18508631) A good search might be ["PHP check role permission"](http://www.google.com/search?q=PHP+check+role+permission).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**STEP-1:** When you validate user login successfully, assign some flag like
 **`$_SESSION['flag'] = "user";`**. And do the same for *admin* like: **`$_SESSION['flag'] = "admin";`**

```
<?php
   ob_start();
   session_start();
   ......
   // login successful, then assign session 
   $_SESSION['flag'] = "admin";   
   // or for normal user
   $_SESSION['flag'] = "user";
```

**STEP-2:** Use this session variable to identify is user is admin or normal user and show or hide the download button like:

```
<?php 
  ob_start();
  session_start();

  if(isset($_SESSION['flag']) && !empty($_SESSION['flag']) && $_SESSION['flag']=="admin"){
       // code here for admin - show download button as you want!
       echo "<button id='btn_download'> Download </button>";
  } // else { // code here for normal user }

?>
```

Comment: geat job man! i will try it. thank you.

Comment: I believe you should check the user's role based on his/her login token on the server side. If you make it part of the session state, then a bad guy will just enable it on the client side. Also see [How to set up user roles and permissions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18508631)

Comment: I solve it with ftp user permission for now but, in future i will need to make something better. This link looks nice i will try something like that. Project on which im working is not for public so ftp user doing great job. Im stuck on stupid reports now and when i solve it i will try to make login better. Thank you a lot. :)